# Merge stored procedure with datatype conversions

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am able to execute my stored procedure. When I execute it a second time instead of updating the existing values same values from source are inserted as new values.

i.e my target has

```
1
2
3
```

When I run the stored procedure a second time, instead of updating 1,2,3, it is inserting the same

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

My condition for when matched then select S.REPORT_TEST1 except T.REPORT_TEST1 is not working.

When I use the same code on a different table which doesn't have data conversions I am able to update.

Can anyone tell where am I going wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Merge]
    INSERT INTO .[dbo].[TARGET](REPORT_TEST1, REPORT_TEST2, REPOST_TEST3)
    FROM (MERGE [dbo].[TARGET] T
          USING (SELECT
                     Cast([REPORT TEST1] as int) [REPORT_TEST1],
                     Cast([REPORT TEST2] as int) [REPORT_TEST2],
                     Cast([REPORT TEST3] as int) [REPORT_TEST3]    
                 FROM 
                     [dbo].[SOURCE]) S ON (T.[REPORT_TEST1] = S.[REPORT_TEST1])

          WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
           THEN INSERT                
                VALUES (S.REPORT_TEST1, S.REPORT_TEST2, S.REPOST_TEST3)

          WHEN MATCHED 
           AND EXISTS (SELECT S.REPORT_TEST1, S.REPORT_TEST2, S.REPOST_TEST3
                       EXCEPT
                       SELECT T.REPORT_TEST1, T.REPORT_TEST2, T.REPOST_TEST3)   
          OUTPUT $ACTION ACTION_OUT, 
                 S.REPORT_TEST1, S.REPORT_TEST2, S.REPOST_TEST3) ;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

would it not suffice to rewrite your WHEN MATCHED statement thusly:

```
WHEN MATCHED 
    AND S.REPORT_TEST2 <> T.REPORT_TEST2 
    AND S.REPORT_TEST3 <> T.REPORT_TEST3 
    (
        SELECT 
            S.REPORT_TEST1
            ,S.REPORT_TEST2
            ,S.REPOST_TEST3
    )
```

I think I understand what you're trying to do, but inside the MERGE context, you're only comparing this row with that row, not the source row against the whole target table.  you could modify the subselect thusly if you're trying to query "this source is not at all in the target"

```
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT 
                    S.REPORT_TEST1
                    ,S.REPORT_TEST2
                    ,S.REPOST_TEST3
                EXCEPT SELECT
                    T2.REPORT_TEST1
                    ,T2.REPORT_TEST2
                    ,T2.REPOST_TEST3
                FROM
                    [dbo].[TARGET] T2

            )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Except in Merge is working,but  ' when not matched by target  then insert ' is inserting the duplicates .